# Angular Form Validation - Displaying validation message after delay

Tags: angular

I've got an Angular form with text inputs.

One input uses the standard Angular `email` validator.

I enable the form submit button when the form is valid.

I previously had the form controls validation triggered on `blur` however, I've been asked to change it back to `change` as the submit button was disabled / greyed out until they clicked out of the input (it was confusing).

So I've changed validation back to `change` but now the error messages appear too soon. When the user enters a single character a validation error is displayed which is annoying as they are entering data.

Any idea how I can validate on `change` but only display the error message after a delay or when they focus out of the input?

I'm sure this is a common problem, but the logic to display the message (below) seems to be used in all examples.

```
<inm-validation-message
 class="validation-container"
 *ngIf="control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched)"
 [control]="control">
</inm-validation-message>
```

Comment: Should work if you just drop the control.dirty condition. Control.touched fires once the blur event fires (when the user loses focus on the element). Or you could make it `control.dirty && control.touched` if you want to keep both.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure that is the best approach, but if you do wanna use it this is how you can delay the error

```
delayedTouched: boolean = false;
```

delay pipe

```
control.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000)  // Delay of 1 second, adjust as needed
).subscribe(() => {
  this.delayedTouched = true;
});
```

use

```
<inm-validation-message
 class="validation-container"
 *ngIf="control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || delayedTouched)"
 [control]="control">
</inm-validation-message>
```

Comment: This works though I find quite annoying that this would have to be added to every FormControl element